# Get image tag from html and string content using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Get image tag from html and string content using JQuery. I want to need image tag form content and replace it with it's alt attribute. For. example:

Given my html string content.

```html
Hello this is long content with multiple images
<img alt=":*" src="kissing_heart.png"> and smiley is <img alt=":D" src="smiley.png">.
```

So how to done?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve.. How the expected html should look?

Comment: English ki to vatt laga di bhai

Comment: I want to img tag in description text .

Comment: Unclear what you asking, try to clear explanation once for all.

Comment: Again, I don't understand what you means by `img tag in description text ` Can you add the html you expect to get?

Comment: what do you means "image tag form content and replace it with it's alt attribute".

Comment: you want replace all <img> by alt of this img tag ??? such as : Hello this is long content with multiple images :* and smiley is :D. huh??

Comment: yeh exactly bro.

Comment: @Mr. LegoBoy how its possible?

Comment: yeah. you can use replaceWith() to resolve this problem http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this output which i have updated with your code. This is what you wanted to be, Only the thing that i did, i have wrapped all the contents inside a div and iterate over each image to replace with its alt attribute.

```js
    $("#mycontent img").each(function () {
        var altText = $(this).attr("alt");
        $(this).replaceWith(altText);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mycontent">
    Hello this is long content with multiple images
    <img alt=":*" src="kissing_heart.png"> and smiley is <img alt=":D" src="smiley.png">.
</div>
```

Comment: Let me check @Sanjay

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery solution, as asked.

```js
$("img").each(function() {
  var altText = $(this).attr("alt");
  $(this).replaceWith(altText);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hello this is long content with multiple images
<img alt=":*" src="kissing_heart.png"> and smiley is <img alt=":D" src="smiley.png">.
```

Comment: I haven't only image tag content but i have image tag with string data are there.